I am not able to understand what TCSAFLUSH does? I've read/watched every documentation and tutorial
I am not able to understand what TCSAFLUSH does. I've read everything online about this, and still it is not clear to me. Can someone please explain this by not giving me the docs link and explain it differently than the docs? Please give step-by-step examples along with the code if possible to explain the working. It will be a big help. I'm creating a project but got stuck here for 2 weeks.
Here is the website source from where I am following the tutorial. Please don't tell me to refer to the docs, I've already read it a million times and cannot understand a thing.
https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html#turn-off-echoing
I also provided the code below for your ease.
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void enableRawMode() {  
    struct termios raw;  
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &raw);  
    raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO);  
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw);
}
int main() {  
    enableRawMode();  
    char c;  
    while (read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) == 1 && c != 'q');  

    return 0;
}

I was following this tutorial https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html#turn-off-echoing attempting to make a Text Editor project in C. But I am not able to understand how does TCSAFLUSH work and why did we use it here. What exactly is its purpose and what if we don't use it.

Did it, still not clear, because it does not show any visible changes.

What does "everything online about this" include?  For example, have you read the POSIX specification of tcsetattr()?  That description seems straightforward: If optional_actions is TCSAFLUSH, the change shall occur after all output written to fildes is transmitted, and all input so far received but not read shall be discarded before the change is made.    In other words, before the changes requested are made, any pending output shall have been sent (with the current terminal settings).  […continued…]

[…continuation…] If there was any input data that had not been read (by user-space code), that input data is discarded.  Then the change to the settings is made.  What don't you understand about that?  Have you worked with RS-232 terminals ever?  Probably not; I haven't done that this millennium, but knowing about how such terminals work might help you understand better what TCSAFLUSH is all about.

I'd like to back Jonathan's comment "What don't you understand about that?" Please [edit] your question to tell us what you specifically don't understand about the description.

I very much doubt that you "read everything online about this." To avoid comments about this, please add what you read the next time.
